# How to set the logo to point to the default site?

Tags: office

Right now each subsite logo points to the subsite's default page. I wanted to point the logo link to the Main Site Collection's Default page so that users can easily go the Main Company's default/landing page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can edit your master page and add the SPlinkbutton.

1. From the Snippet Gallery, copy and paste the default SiteLogo code
   snippet into your master page into the appropriate place you want it
   to be displayed.
2. In the SiteLogo code, search for SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink to find the relevant opening and closing tags. Now simply change the tag names to SharePoint:SPLinkButton instead.
3. Then simply add the attribute NavigateUrl to this tag and set it’s value to “~sitecollection/”.

Read complete post here: https://samanalie.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/site-logo-link-to-root-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013/

Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582710/sharepoint-redirect-site-logo-link-to-the-root-site-collection-home-page